# How to restrict users to send and receive messages within rosteritem in ejabberd?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api

I have created users in ejabberd server using REST API.
Using `send_message` API, I could send messages directly to any user using their jabberd id.

But I need to restrict the users to send/receive messages only with their roster items.

For example,

There is two users, `user1@localhost` and `user2@localhost`

Now the `user2` is not the roster item of `user1`.
Here, the `user2` should be restricted to send direct messages to `user1`.

Only after adding `user2` to the roster item of `user1`, the `user2` could send messages to `user1` and it should be **handles in the backed**.

Is there any ejabberd modules to do it or is there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [mod_block_strangers](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-block-strangers):

> This module allows to block/log messages coming from an unknown entity. If a writing entity is not in your roster, you can let this module drop and/or log the message.